# How to move file from one users account to another? Permission denied.

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, permission, file-transfer

I'm trying to move the file of a virtual machine from one users account to the other. So basically I want to move `/Users/joe/Win7.vm` to `/Users/jane/Win7.vm` but I can't figure out how to do it through Finder because I can't get to the root directory (`/`). I tried moving it using the `mv` command in Terminal and it said permission denied. Is tried `sudo mv` but it just said "sorry". I also tried changing its permission (`chmod`) but it wouldn't let me (and when I tried `sudo chmod`, it literally said "sorry").

I'm logged in as administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a permissions issue. To resolve simply, first copy the file to /Users/Shared/, then copy again from there, then try to troubleshoot your permissions issues afterwards. You are logged in as administrator, yet you still are lacking the authority to escalate to root or change permissions, and that is odd. Even as admin, you would still need root access to move a file belonging to one user to another users' account. In Terminal, try `sudo bash` and enter your password when prompted. To use mv command, the syntax is `mv /path/to/origin/file /path/to/destination/directory/`

Also, changing permissions with `chmod` doesn't change ownership. You use [`chown`](https://developer.apple.com/librarY/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/chown.8.html) for that.

Comment: Is it because the vm file is actually a directory, not a file (or something like that)?

Comment: Good point; while it shouldn't effect mv or Finder, it does affect chmod. Should try `sudo chmod -R 775 folder` and `chown -R user:group folder` -- the `-R` makes the command act recursively to all enclosed files and folders.

Comment: Got it working. I forgot vmware files are more like folders. I used `sudo chmod -R 775 folder` and then was able to move it. I wasn't able to access it still and I found that I needed chmod -R 777 to recursively change the permissions of all the files inside the vm file/folder.

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler option exists via `/Users/[a username]/Public/Drop\ Box`.

Simply drop the file(s) into this folder in the receiving user's homedir and you are good to go after logging in as said, receiving user.